# How do I get <hr> margin working?

Tags: html, css, overflow, margin, hidden

I am trying to add a "hr" in my Wordpress pages to space out my content. I have styled it as follows:

```
p {
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
color: #555555; 
font-family: Helvetica, 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, 'Lato', sans-serif; 
font-size: 16px; 
font-weight: 400; 
line-height: 1.25em;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0 0 12px 0;
}

h4 {
color: #111111;
font-family: Helvetica, 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif; 
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 900; 
line-height: 1.2em;
margin: 0 0 8px 0; 
}

hr { 
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 1px;
background: #cccccc; 
border: none;
outline: none;
padding: 0px !important;
margin: 26px 0 13px 0 !important; 
}
```

The HTML I am using in the Wordpress page is as follows:

```
<h4>Make your selection</h4>
<p>
<input type="radio" name="left-or-right" value="left" checked="checked" />
Turn Left<br />
<input type="radio" name="left-or-right" value="right" /> Turn Right</p>

<hr>
```

My problem with the "hr" is that it's margin-top 26px doesn't push it away from the "p" above. Instead, the margins of the "hr" and "p" seem to overlap.

So far, I have been able to fix this problem by adding this:

```
.generic-container {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
}

<div class="generic-container">
<h4>Make your selection</h4>
<p>
<input type="radio" name="left-or-right" value="left" checked="checked" />
Turn Left<br />
<input type="radio" name="left-or-right" value="right" /> Turn Right
</p>
</div>

<hr>
```

It seems a bit long winded to add

```
<div class="generic-container">
```

at the top of each section of the page, and then adding the "/div" to close it off above every "hr".

I have tried adding "overflow: hidden;" into the...

```
p

main.content

.entry-content
```

...but this doesn't seem to work.

Please can anyone give me some suggestions as to how to make the "hr" margin activate, to move it away from the elements above it?

Thank you for reading.

---

**Added below after replies up to @symlink :**

Thank you all for your replies.
Despite changing "p" margin-bottom to padding-bottom, this code 'below' still doesn't work (still trying without "generic-container"):

CSS

```
.width-80pc {
width: 80%;
}
.width-20pc {
width: 20%;
}

.float-left {
float: left;
}

.float-right {
float: right;
}

p.toby-small-text {
color: inherit;
font-weight: inherit;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 1.25em;
padding-bottom: 5px;
margin: 0px !important; 
}

.text-align-left {
text-align: left;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="width-80pc float-left">
<h4>This review is about this service</h4>
<p><input type="radio" name="service" value="one" disabled> Service One</p>
</div>

<div class="width-20pc float-right">
<p class="toby-small-text text-align-left"><a>Service Two</a></p>
</div>

<hr>
```

---

**Added below after my reply 'comment' to @Marc Audet :**

The code works at keeping the boxes above the hr away from the hr, but not boxes underneath it.

Following the suggestion from Marc, I have created this to keep boxes **above** and **beneath** the hr away from the hr :

CSS

```
.width-80pc {
width: 80%;
outline: 2px dotted blue;
}
.width-20pc {
width: 20%;
outline: 2px dotted purple;
}
.float-left {
float: left;
}
.float-right {
float: right;
}
p.toby-small-text {
color: inherit;
font-weight: inherit;
font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 1.25em;
margin: 0px !important;
}
.text-align-left {
text-align: left;
}

hr {
clear: both;  /* Takes care of you floated elements */
padding-top: 40px;
/* padding-bottom: 20px; This doesn't create space under the hr line */
border: none;
border-bottom: 2px solid red;
height: 0px;
background: transparent;
}

.after-hr {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
height: 20px;
background: transparent;
}

/* This doesn't seem to work
.after-hr::after {
clear: both;
}
*/

h4, p, p.toby-small-text {
padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="width-80pc float-left">
<h4>This review is about this service</h4>
<p><input type="radio" name="service" value="one" disabled>Service One</p>
</div>

<div class="width-20pc float-right">
<p class="toby-small-text text-align-left"><a>Service Two</a></p>
</div>

<hr><div class="after-hr"></div>

<div class="width-80pc float-left">
<p>I also need the "hr" to keep away from the boxes underneath it.<br>
By creating ".after-hr" I seem to be able to make some space under it.<br>
I tried to use "hr::after" but it doesn't seem to work.</p>
</div>
```

If anyone can suggest how to create space beneath the "hr" without having to use the "hr" with the "after-hr" in the HTML, I welcome any suggestions.

Perhaps some way to get "hr::after" doing the job.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach based on your snippet that has floated elements.

On the `hr` element, you can add `clear: both` so that the `hr` element is positioned below all the floated elements.

To take care of the vertical whitespace at the top of the horizontal rule,
make sure that the border is set to show only the bottom (or top) and add some padding to the top to control the separation.

If you want to control the spacing after the `hr` element, you can adjust `margin-bottom`, as shown below.  This seems to work pretty well.

I tested this in Firefox, should work in other browsers.

```css
.width-80pc {
  width: 80%;
  outline: 1px dotted blue;
}
.width-20pc {
  width: 20%;
  outline: 1px dotted blue;
}
.float-left {
  float: left;
}
.float-right {
  float: right;
}
p.toby-small-text {
  color: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.25em;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin: 0px !important;
}
.text-align-left {
  text-align: left;
}
hr {
  clear: both; /* takes care of you floated elements */
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
p.extra {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="width-80pc float-left">
  <h4>This review is about this service</h4>
  <p><input type="radio" name="service" value="one" disabled>Service One</p>
</div>

<div class="width-20pc float-right">
  <p class="toby-small-text text-align-left"><a>Service Two</a></p>
</div>

<hr>

<p class="extra">Some more text.</p>
```

Comment: Hi @Marc thanks you for your help. I tried your code and it works well, keeping the above elements away from the hr. Unfortunately, I couldn't keep elements below the hr away from it. Adding "padding-bottom" just added more padding to the top. However, using your method I have added something to it ".after-hr"

Comment: @Toby I took a second look at the problem and you can get some control over the whitespace following the `hr` element by setting a value to the bottom margin.  Please see updated answer.

Comment: Hi @Marc, I dismissed the idea of going back to the "margin" due its initial "margin-top" fail, which motivated me to post my question here. However, I have added a "margin-bottom" as you have suggested and it seems to work fine. I will keep my eye on this as I'm using a lot of different sections on my WP pages. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like [collapsing margins issue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing). You can fix it by using `padding` for the `p` instead of `margin`.

Comment: Hi @Nora thank you for the suggestion. Have just tried this and it does work for some of the sections, like a standard paragraph above the hr. 

However, it doesn't work when I have a hr below two divs, one floating left (80% width), and the other floating right (20% width).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried viewing it another browser? I'm using Chrome and honestly it looks fine (the first bit, prior to adding generic container), it shows up below the paragraph and I don't see anything overlapping. (I can't add pictures yet to show you sadly).

Comment: Hi @Jayc, thanks for replying here. 
I too am using Chrome. 

The visible elements don't overlap, it's the margins that overlap. The space between the visible elements should be much bigger.

Answer (score 0):

It's not long-winded to add the `generic-container` div. What is happening when you apply `overflow:hidden` is you are forcing `generic-containter` to establish a new **Block Formatting Context Root**. This does several things, one of which is to ensure that the margins inside the div are contained within the div. The good news is you don't need any of the CSS you added to the container div except for `overflow:hidden`.

```css
p {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    color: #555555;
    font-family: Helvetica, 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.25em;
    margin: 0 0 12px 0;
}

h4 {
    color: #111111;
    font-family: Helvetica, 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 900;
    line-height: 1.2em;
    margin: 0 0 8px 0;
}

hr {
    height: 1px;
    background: #cccccc;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    margin: 26px 0 13px 0;
}

.generic-container {
    background:lightblue;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="generic-container">
    <h4>Make your selection</h4>
    <p>
        <input type="radio" name="left-or-right" value="left" checked="checked" /> Turn Left
        <br />
        <input type="radio" name="left-or-right" value="right" /> Turn Right</p>
</div>
<hr>
```

Read more about the Block Formatting Context Here:

http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-block-formatting-contexts-in-css/

Comment: Thank you @symlink  I'll be able to remove the code I don't need.

As some of my pages have a lot of sections that need to be broken up with "hr", is it not possible to add the "overflow:hidden" to one or two divs in the css so I don't need to fill my pages with 

    <div class="generic-container">

Comment: You will have to apply `overflow:hidden` (or one of the other CSS values that triggers a BFC Root) to every block container that you want to behave this way. Child containers of BFC Root containers don't inherit the formatting rules of their parent. E.g., notice how the p tags in the yellow block container in https://jsfiddle.net/6La4cacw/ have margins outside their parent.

Comment: I have now simplified the "generic-container" as per your recommendations. 
Many thanks